# Pygame not working

Tags: pygame

```
while done == False:
    for event in py.event.get():
        if event.type == py.QUIT:
            done = True
        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_UP:
                player_y += 1
```

this is my code and my debugger keeps saying that KEYDOWN is not defined. Help please

Answer (score 4):

include this on the top of your code:

```
from pygame import KEYDOWN, K_UP
```

Add more keys such as `K_LEFT, K_RIGHT, K_UP, K_DOWN, K_e` if you like

Answer (score 2):

the full call is `pygame.KEYDOWN` etc

instead of manually typing out the ones that you need just add this below your `import pygame` line `from pygame.locals import *` this should work for all the keys you need.

Answer (score -1):

Include this in your code or it wont work

```py
while done == False:
    for event in py.event.get():
        if event.type == py.QUIT:
            done = True
        if event.type == py.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == py.K_UP:
                player_y += 1
```